# Change few configure time options for GCC compiler 4.1.2

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, cross-compiling, toolchain

Linux PC, and cross compilation toolchain for arm, gcc version 4.1.2 (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc). I want to make changes in the prebuilt toolchain - modify some GCC compiler configuration options (was set at configure time) without rebuilding the compiler: is that possible? In particular, I need to change directory specified in options arguments `--with-sysroot`, `--prefix` and `--with-gxx-include-dir`. Can I make this without recompiling the source, by applying the changes to gcc binary use **sed** stream editor? (replace directory)

Answer (score 1):

I did things like that years ago - back then it worked ;-)

You need to ensure your new path is the same length (or shorter) than the one that is there, and then replace the value "in place" - i.e. don't change the string length:

```
"/the_old_path\0" 
becomes 
"/new_path\0ath\0"
```

I don't recommend it, but can't hurt to try (after you've backed up the original)

Comment: Path differs in length, old path: `/opt/emlix/foo/sysroot`, new: `/opt/emlix/bar1234/sysroot`.

Comment: If the new path length is longer you'll probably run into all sorts of problems. Can you do anything with links ? like making the old point to the new (then you don't need to edit exes at all) or a link to part of it (say /mydir -> /opt/emlix) to bring the new path in shorter? (I haven't counted chars to see if that sample link works)

Comment: well, all the toolchain gcc binaries and libraries are precompiled, I have no configuration files and scripts to rebuild the entire toolchain from scratch.

Comment: @minto As per the question and answer - you can use sed to change the paths. I have personal experience in shortening the paths - it works (or it did when I did it years ago ;-) Making the paths longer means offsets etc in files change and so I wouldn't like to suggest it will work. I'm suggesting you can possibly overcome that problem by making the paths shorter by using soft links.